# Specifying APT proxy from the command line

Tags: apt, apt-cacher

Is there a way of specifying APT proxy without needing to use a file (think apt.conf)?

Answer (score 6):

Any option accepted by *apt.conf* can be specified on the command line with `--option`. An example for APT proxy, assuming **`apt-cacher-ng`**:

```
apt update --option Acquire::HTTP::Proxy=http://localhost:3142
```

Equivalent of this in */etc/apt/apt.conf*:

```
Acquire::HTTP::Proxy "http://localhost:3142";
```